# Чи можна вживати слово "пралка"?

Tags: вживання-слів

Зустрів таке речення "Дарина одразу ж закидає у пралку білизну, складену у великій солом'яній корзині" ("Гніздо горлиці" - Леся Олендій). А також бачив, що слово "пралка" вживатється у різних статтях в Інтернеті (наприклад [тут](http://blog.comfy.ua/ua/osnovni-prichini-polomok-pralnikh-mashin-i-poradi-shhodo-yikh-uniknennya/) та [тут](http://shlyahta.com.ua/20-rechei-iaki-robliat-usi-liudy-koly-ikh-nikhto-ne-bachyt/)). Однак, ввівши це слово у СУМі, я його там не знайшов. Отож, чи можна взагалі вживати слово "пралка" в українській мові, наприклад, у літературних творах чи творах для ЗНО?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Слово пралка ніде не зафіксовано в українських тлумачних словниках. Сюди належать [СУМ-11], [ВЕСУМ](https://r2u.org.ua/vesum/?w=%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%BA%D0%B0), [Словник української мови за ред. Б. Грінченка]. Такого ж слова не подають й [Онлайн-коректор](http://onlinecorrector.com.ua/%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%BA%D0%B0), [Мова - ДНК нації](https://ukr-mova.in.ua/search?id=32&search=%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%BA%D0%B0),[Офіційний сайт української мови](https://ukrainskamova.com/search/?q=%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%BA%D0%B0&t=0). Єдину інформацію знайшла у перекладних польсько-українських словниках, зокрема на сайті [Glosbe](https://uk.glosbe.com/pl/uk/pralka):

> **pralka** - **пральна машина**, пралька, шайба.

Отже, слово пралка, ймовірно, є скалькованим із польської мови й активно використовується у розмовній. Можливо, його подадуть вже у новому СУМ-20. Однак станом на сьогодні у наукових текстах, зокрема і в ЗНО, використовувати НЕ варто.

Comment: можливо воно скальковане з рос. *стіралка*?

Comment: @Yola, хіба утворення за аналогією (-алка), але, думаю, швидше з польської, бо все ж там таке слово є, проте використовується більше в розмовній, наукова назва пральної машини дещо інша, але от пригадати не можу (точно знаю, що в назві є agd). Крім того, слово "пралка" вживають здебільшого в нас, на заході, на сході ж кажуть "стіралка", на скільки я знаю.

Answer (score 1):

Словники такого слова не подають. Але словники лише фіксують реальний ужиток, і завжди із запізненням. А оскільки пральні машини в сучасному побуті використовують часто, а словосполучення «пральна машина» доволі довге й незручне, то рано чи пізно якесь коротке позначення цього пристрою ввійде в загальновизнану норму (цілком можливо, що й *пралка* чи *пралька*).

Наскільки я можу судити, *пралка* й *пралька* вже вживаються навіть у книжках:

- **пралка**:

  - > Якийсь поет-першокурсник, котрий тепер торгує пралками у Восо чи страховими полісами в Індіанаполісі? // Стівен Кінг «Сяйво» у перекладі Олександра Красюка.
  - [інші трапляння в «ГРАК»](http://kontext.parasolcorpus.org/view?q=~hWsM9SDgun08&corpname=grac5)
- **пралька**:

  - > Це, звичайно, дотепно і цікаво — писати про відомих авторів, смішно уявити собі їх — таких різних і таких знаменитих, як мусять варити собі обіди, прати шкарпетки, допомагати один одному відкривати ножем поламану пральку і як вечорами, розповідаючи щось одне одному, розливають вино на обрус. // Софія Андрухович «Жінки їхніх чоловіків».
  - [інші трапляння в «ГРАК»](http://kontext.parasolcorpus.org/view?q=~ncn6NAjggGQG&corpname=grac5)

Тож я не бачу ніяких перепон, щоб застосовувати це слово принаймні в розмовному стилі. Тільки лишається питання «пралка чи пралька».